# Data on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an app that requires the user to be able to request a server and get back some JSON Data. Here are my question and my reasoning behind it:

1) Would this require the user to have "Data" on their cell phone plan?

Dealing with Android, I have figured out that when I do not have "Data" on my cellphone plan, that I can not access the internet, but I am allowed to use twitter. Instagram, however does not load when I do not have "Data".

When I do have Data on my cellphone plan, I am allowed to go onto the internet, use twitter, and use Instagram.

Will my App act as twitter or Instagram in this case? and how do I make the app work without a Data plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app needs to access the Internet (which is does to reach the server) then the user must either be connected via WiFi or if connected via cellular, the user must have a data plan.

A cellular connection with no data plan will prevent your app from accessing the Internet.

Comment: In this case, how would my twitter work on my phone without the Data plan?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of connection to the Internet to be able to access the internet.

You don't need a data plan, if your device is connected over wifi (such as iPod touches) then that will allow a connection to the internet.

The apps you mention do run on a device without an internet connection because they handle the case where there is not an internet connection sensibly, and although they load, they don't crash because of a lack of connection.

If you want to do the same thing, then you need to have a way of handling this too.

Comment: How would this be the case? If there is not Data plan? On Android, i can still get realtime tweets without having a data plan.

Comment: Are you sure the Android device isn't connected to a WiFi network? Are you sure that you are seeing the latest tweets, rather than a cache of the last time the device was connected to a network? It's not magic; without a network connection you can't get on the network.

Comment: Yes, i am absolutely sure. I tested this out to make sure.

Comment: Then I must change my career immediately. Clearly Android devices can access the internet without an internet connection. - They are magical.

Comment: All i know is that i do not have a data plan and i get my tweets. There is no reason to be ugly about it.

Comment: Ugly? You're talking about accessing the internet without a connection. Are you sure you don't have a WiFi connection? Are you sure there is not 3G or other network connection provided by the phone?

Comment: Yes, there is 3G, BUT i do not have Data on my Phone. Meaning i cant search the web are use many apps. In this case, i was able to use twitter somehow.

Comment: Maybe you have a special phone plan that allows you to connect to Twitter without an data allowance? All I'm saying is that __you do__ have a connection to the internet. WiFi, 3G or special allowance.